# CGI not executing local script

Tags: bash, apache, cgi

I am trying to call a local script when somebody loads a cgi page from my apache server.

The cgi page is built inside of a shell script on my raspberry pi, containing the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python ignitor.py&
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
cat /home/pi/Detonator/redir.html
```

However, The python script never gets called when the cgi page loads, but I know the script works, because if I call it manually, it gets executed.

I checked all of the chmod's already, but is there some apache policy working against me here, or what is going on?

Comment: Can the apache user `sudo` to root like that? I would hope not for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to rewrite the script to run on a local user level using wiringpi